# Getting height and width of objects after connected component analysis

Tags: matlab

I want to find the width and height of the connected component objects using regionprops 'BoundingBox' property in matlab.I find and mark the rectangles but I don't know how to extract the height and width.So how can I extract it?My code is given below

```
cc=bwconncomp(im);    
stats=regionprops(cc,'BoundingBox');    
for n = 1 : length(stats)    
     thisBB = stats(n).BoundingBox;    
     rectangle('Position', [thisBB(1),thisBB(2),thisBB(3),thisBB(4)],...    
     'EdgeColor','r','LineWidth',1 )    
 end
```

Answer (score 1):

You have already extracted the width and height of the rectangle. The output of `'BoundingBox'` in the BW case is

```
[ corner_x corner_y, width, height]
```

`thisBB(3)` is therefore the width, and `thisBB(4)` is the height.

The [`rectangle`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rectangle.html#inputarg_pos) function expects exactly this as input: `[x,y,w,h]`.